# Is $\pmb{x}<\pmb{y}$ implies $A\pmb{x}<A\pmb{y}$ when $A$ is positive definite?

Tags: inequality, matrix-equations, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I think the title is self-explanatory. I would like to have a small proof supporting your statement. $\pmb{x}$ and $\pmb{y}$ denote vectors and $A$ denote a square positive definite matrix.

Comment: What does $\pmb{x}<\pmb{y}$ mean?

Comment: Component-wise inequality. @Arthur. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, w=2v$.

Comment: Side note: This answer doesn't disprove $\pmb{x}\leq \pmb{y}$ (if that's something one cares about). However, if you subtract some small $\varepsilon$ from the off-diagonal entries, the matrix is still positive definite but this time the first component of $Av$ is strictly larger than the first component of $Aw$.

Comment: Or take $v=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}, w=\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\end{bmatrix}$, then $v\leq w$, $Av=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, Aw=\begin{bmatrix}0\\4\end{bmatrix}$, so $Av\not\leq Aw$.